# Why does Rails think my database is MongoDB, when it's SQLite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sqlite

My database.yml file says

```
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

When I run rails server, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

I grep search my project, no mondodb written anywhere..
I am using cucumber for BDD.
And when I run rake, I get:

```
Please install the mongodb adapter: `gem install activerecord-mongodb-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/mongodb_adapter)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Got any MongoDB related gems, such as MongoMapper, in your Gemfile, or any gems depending on it? A simple grep wouldn't reveal the latter.

Comment: Nope, I've removed all gems from the gemset and started over.

Comment: Is that literally what your database.yml file says or is the piece you quoted under a 'development:' line?